# Haskell program run in background does not redirect output to file unless buffer mode is NoBuffering

Tags: haskell

I've got a Haskell program that logs some data periodically.  When I run it as a background process, my logging statements are not redirected to my log file unless I change the buffering mode to `NoBuffering`.  I do not understand why the default setting of `LineBuffering` does not work.

Here is my test program:

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)
import System.IO (BufferMode(..), hSetBuffering, stdout)

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ do
  -- hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  threadDelay $ 1000 * 1000
  putStrLn "log"
```

When I run this program normally in the console, I get the expected output:

```
$ ./Main
log
log
log
```

Outputting "log" once per second.  When I redirect it to a file, it also works as expected:

```
$ ./Main >log
^C
$ cat log
log
log
log
```

However, when I run it as a background process:

```
$ ./Main >log &
$ cat log
```

then there is nothing written to the log file, unless I uncomment the line that sets stdout buffering to `NoBuffering`.

I used the `hGetBuffering` function to determine the default buffering setting, and it is `LineBuffering`.  Considering that each "log" statement is indeed on a different line, why do I need to set the buffering mode to `NoBuffering` in order for the logs to be written to the log file?  I.E. Why does the buffer not flush at each newline when the buffer mode is set to `LineBuffering`?

Comment: Have you tried setting the buffer mode to `LineBuffering`, or are you just assuming that's the default? (It's more complicated than that. Specifically, the default is `LineBuffering` for tty devices and `BlockBuffering` otherwise.)

Comment: @Carl When I add at the beginning of the program `buffering <- hGetBuffering stdout` and `putStrLn (show buffering)` the output is `LineBuffering`, and from that I assumed it was the default.  However, if I run `hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering` I actually get the same output as if I run `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` -- so apparently it was *not* the default, and `hGetBuffering` actually returned the wrong value.

Comment: Or maybe it's `LineBuffering` when I don't run it as a background task, and `BlockBuffering` when I do run it as a background task.

Comment: Confirmed, that is what's happening.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Maybe you could answer your own question, so we have an answer here?

Comment: If you answer I'll accept it, then we'll both get some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments on question.  Adding this answer mainly just so that the question is marked as "Answered".

It was *not* necessary to set the buffering mode strictly to `NoBuffering` -- either that or `LineBuffering` causes logging output to be created as expected.

The problem was that the default was `BlockBuffering`, not `LineBuffering`, when the program was run in background mode.  I did not think that running the program in background mode would affect the default setting for stdout buffering.

Comment: See here on how to set this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59554287/1663462