# No stdout/stderror output when running Haskell application in Kubernetes

Tags: haskell, kubernetes, output-buffering

I've run into a very strange issue where I don't seem to be getting any stdout/stderr output from a Haskell application when run via Kubernetes.

I'm using very basic `putStrLn` to write to stdout.

If I manually enter the container within the Kubernetes environment and run the application via the shell - I see the expected output.

What may be the cause of this issue/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is caused by the output buffering being set in "block" mode when being output to the kubernetes logging.

Fixed via setting the buffering to `LineBuffering`:

```
import System.IO

...
  hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
  hSetBuffering stderr LineBuffering
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode

> The default buffering mode when a handle is opened is
>   implementation-dependent and may depend on the file system object
>   which is attached to that handle. For most implementations, physical
>   files will normally be block-buffered and terminals will normally be
>   line-buffered.

Thanks to Jesse Kempf from the fp slack for pointing me to this!